# How to add implode variable to assorted text box values

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms, implode

I have the following three pages of code. The 1st page asks the user which music genres they like (there will eventually be 20+ genres). The 2nd page asks the user to rank the genres they have selected and the 3rd page sorts and displays their ranking.

This first page asks the user to pick which genres they like:

```
<form id="genre" name="genre" method="post" action="musicsell.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Rap" value="Rap"/>Rap<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="HipHop" value="HipHop"/>HipHop<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="RnB" value="RnB"/>RnB<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Rock" value="Rock"/>Rock<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" id="Jazz"value="Jazz"/>Jazz<br />

  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
```

This second asks them to rank (prioritize) the genres they have selected with 1 being the best:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="musicresults.php">
<?php
$name = $_POST['genre'];

if(isset($_POST['genre'])) {
foreach ($name as $genre){

?>

<input type="number" required="required" id="<?php echo $genre ?>" name="music[<?php echo $genre ?>]" max="3" min="1" /><?php echo $genre ?><br /> 

<?php
    }
} 
?>

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></form>
```

The third and last page sorts and echos the results:

```
<?php
//Get the form results (which has been converted to an associative array) from the $_POST super global
$musicgenres = $_POST['music'];

//Sort the values by rank and keep the key associations.
asort($musicgenres, SORT_NUMERIC );

//Loop over the array in rank order to print out the values.
foreach($musicgenres as $music => $rank)
{
   echo "$music is your $rank choice";
   echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

An example of the results:

Rap is your 1 choice
HipHop is your 2 choice
RnB is your 3 choice

But how can I put a separate set of code to the last page that I could echo a variable (e.g. `echo "musicstring = $musicstring";`) that would display a result like:

> musicstring = Rap, HipHop, RnB

I think an implode function is needed but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the list need any sorting, or do you just want to see all the elements of the $musicstring list?

Comment: Hi Surreal Dreams. The list needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

yes, `implode` is what you need:

```
echo implode(' ,', array_values($musicgenres));
```

Comment: `implode` doesn't add a trailing 'glue' character, so you can skip the `rtrim`.

Comment: Hi taxicala, adding your code resulting in  "1, 2, 3" and not "Rap, HipHop, RnB"

Comment: I did not notice you had a key/value pair array, I've just edited the answer adding array values so you only implode the values of the array

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Yes, implode function will work for you.

The **implode()** function returns a string from the elements of an array.

**Syntax:** 
implode(separator,array)

find **implode()** documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

update the foreach function like this:

```
foreach($musicgenres as $music => $rank)
{
   array_push($musicstring, $music);   
   echo "$music is your $rank choice";
   echo "<br>";
}
```

and then, You may have to add following code in last:

```
 $musicstring = implode(", ", $musicgenres);
 echo $musicstring;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Narain, when I added the code I get an "unexpected '<' " error so I removed the <pre> tags but then the result was "1, 2, 3" and not "Rap, HipHop, RnB"

Comment: yeah, don't include the <pre> sorry i forgot to remove.  and change foreach function to this:      //Loop over the array in rank order to print out the values.
foreach($musicgenres as $music => $rank)
{
   array_push($musicstring, $music);                                                                               echo "$music is your $rank choice";
   echo "<br>";
}  and then this will work:                                                                    $musicstring = implode(", ", $musicgenres);
    echo $musicstring;

Comment: updated the answer, see above. for more see the php array documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: The simple array is no problem but with the array push I'm getting "Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Comment: it seems like, we are not passing array in the 1st param, it's found to be null to the compiler.. try to declare the variable before for loop to the empty array.  find the right syntax on by w3schools php documentation.. $musicstring = array(); //